# The signature of a simple symmetric bilinear form: $\langle A , B \rangle = \text{Tr}(AB)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, bilinear-form

I want to verify that what I am doing is correct.

Let $V = \{A \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) : \text{Tr}(A) = 0\}$ and $\langle - , - \rangle$ be the symmetric bilinear form $\langle A, B \rangle = \text{Tr}(AB)$.  The set $\mathbb{B} = \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ where $e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, e_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a basis for $V$ that is orthogonal with respect to $\langle - , - \rangle$.
Now I easily compute $\langle e_1 , e_1 \rangle = 2, \langle e_2 , e_2 \rangle = 0, \langle e_3 , e_3 \rangle = 0$.  Therefore the signature of $\langle - , - \rangle$ is $(1,0,2)$.

I would like to know if this is right and/or if there are any other approaches to take.

Comment: I get $\left<e_1,e_1\right>=2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That is correct, I made a typo - will edit now.

Comment: I don't see that $e_2$ and $e_3$ are orthogonal.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Now that I check again, you are right.  This is not an orthogonal basis.

Comment: In general one cannot determine the signature from the values $\langle E_a, E_a \rangle$ for a fixed basis $(E_a)$ alone.

Comment: @Travis If the fixed basis $(E_a)$ is orthogonal, then can I determine the signature from the values $\langle E_a, E_a \rangle$?  I realize the basis I provided is not orthogonal.  In order to determine the signature I am going to look for another basis which is orthogonal.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, that's right (really above I should say a "...general fixed basis..."---e.g., if $(E_a)$ is a null basis, $\langle E_a, E_a \rangle = 0$ for all $a$ but some nonzero bilinear forms have null bases). And notice that since $e_2$ and $e_3$ are isotropic we have, e.g., expanding gives $\langle e_2 + e_3 , e_2 + e_3 \rangle = 2 \langle e_2, e_3 \rangle$. Another choice, sometimes useful if you have CAS handy, is to pick any basis and compute the eigenvalues of the matrix with $(a, b)$ entry $\langle E_a, E_b \rangle$. The signs of the eigenvalues tell you the signature of the form.